# Confused about Codility demo test

Tags: c#, algorithm

I took the [Codility.com demo test](http://codility.com/demo/run/).

My program returned the wrong value for one of the unit tests:

> TEST
>   extreme_large_numbers 
>   Sequence with extremly large numbers testing arithmetic overflow.
>
> TIME
>   0.056 s.
>
> RESULT
>   WRONG ANSWER 
>   got 2, but it is not equilibrium point, sum[0..1]=4294967294, sum[3..3]=-2

Ok, since I couldn't see the problem in my code at first, I tried running it in a Visual Studio project.  Then the compiler caught that `4294967294` was too big for an `int`.  It needs to be an `uint`, or a `long`.  So I changed everything to `long` and it worked in VS.

However, the demo test does not let you change the function input/return types to `long`.

- 2,147,483,647 (largest signed 32-bit int)
- 4,294,967,294 (number given by Codility.com unit test)

**Can someone please explain how this program can possibly work properly with `4294967294` as one of the data values in an `int[]`?**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only need to take the large range into account while computing the result, the final result will not be out of bounds. Still it seems that your solution is not very efficient, you can reach a linear runtime on this one.

**Edit:** You can look at the revision history to see code that runs fast and scores 100. ;-)

Comment: 1. I agree my solution is not the most efficient, but I'm not a brilliant programmer and it's only 30 min! 2. I don't think you answered my question; how can I compare values if I don't have a large enough data type to store `4294967294`??

Comment: 1. I was just pointing it out... 2. You don't, those are in fact negative values, but the sums of large values exceed the `int` range.

Comment: I see... `2147483647 * 2 = 4294967294`  They are intentionally blowing out the `int` data type :(

Comment: Sure they are - this is what maked the Codility tasks great: most are very simple, but with subtle issues to consider.

Comment: Fair enough! I re-edited it, so that one can look at the revision history for spoilers... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A `Swift 2.2` version of @Lurcero code that runs fast and scores 100:

```
public func solution(inout A : [Int]) -> Int {

let n = A.count

if n == 0 { return -1 }

if n == 1 { return 0 }

var right : Int64 = A.reduce(0, combine: +)

var left : Int64 = 0

for i in 0..<n {

    right -= A[i]

    if left == right {
        return i
    }
    left += A[i]
}

return -1
}
```